# Error while registering a custom workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

While registering a custom workflow using plugin registration tool in SDK I m facing this issue. As you can see no DLL is showing in this package. what is the problem here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is solved after adding one `package` type project into that solution. that `workflow` project requires `RegisterFile.crmregister` to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because your class and functions in that class are not `public`.